# How to access electron app's current browserWindow?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, electron

I'm stuck on a particular point with my Electron app:

When I open the devTools, I call `mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()` from the app's menu. It's working fine on `mainWindow`.

The problem appears on child windows, opened by `window.open()`: the app menu is still working on every window, but it always call **mainWindow's devtools** (which is normal, since I told it to do so), where I would like to get **current** window's ones.

So I wonder if there is a way to call something like `currentWindow.webContents.openDevTools()` ? I found nothing in the documentation nor on SO nor by googling, so I guess I might haev missed something.

Let me precise a few things:

- I'm still a newbie with Electron
- I have no control on the pages that are called in the app, I'm trying to use electron as a kind of "restricted browser" to ship with a PHP-based application

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a bit more reading, I just found out that `BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()` is exactly what I was looking for.

So in my app menu, I juste call `BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().webContents.openDevTools()`, and it works as I expected.